# Passing RGBA32F texture to a shader as R32F for imageAtomic operations and accessing components

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

Is it possible to pass a 3D RGBA32F texture to shader as a type that is compatible with the imageAtomic operations (i.e. R32F), and then modifying somehow the ivec3 index such that the appropriate components of the RGBA32F texture are accessed deterministically?

I know this is possible with buffer's where the indexing is much more straight forward, but the ivec3 would seem to prevent clever index manipulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `R32F` is [*not* compatible with atomic image operations](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Atomic_limitations). Only integer formats are. Unless you're using [an NVIDIA extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/shader_atomic_float.txt).

Second, the [image format compatibility rules](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Format_compatibility) do not allow you to pretend that an RGBA32F texture is an R32UI texture. They work based on compatible texel sizes, and RGBA32F is 128-bits in size, while R32UI is 32-bits.

Comment: Oops, meant R32UI. And thanks for the link, that was the resources I was looking for.